# Glitch on transition between views

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

For some reason, the transition between some views on my app has a weird glitch. It seems that the view is opened but is closed in the same time.

Here is a video with details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4ohaoc56w0

Any idea on what may be causing this issue?

This is in my app.js:

```
// O Festival

.state('appFestival.o-festival', {
    url: '/o-festival',

    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/festival/o-festival.html',
            controller: 'FestivalCtrl'
        }
    }
})

// O Festival >> Line-up

.state('appFestival.line-up', {
    url: '/line-up',

    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/festival/line-up.html',
            controller: 'FestivalCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

This is my HTML (how i'm calling the child view):

```
        <a href="#/app/line-up" class="opt-line-up">
            <span class="titulo">
                <img src="img/icons/ico-music.png" class="ico" /> 
                Line-up!
            </span>
        </a>
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you have a code sample?

Comment: @AdamG I've edited my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using iOS9, this glitch is caused by the regression of `uiwebview`.

I had this problem couple days ago and solved it using [this](https://gist.github.com/IgorMinar/863acd413e3925bf282c) patch:

Let me know if it works.